# problema con rows en bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5

Hola tengo esta pagina web, y el problema es que queria mostrar las dos rows en dos filas separadas y no como dos columnas que es como se muestra. Es decir quiero que aparezca una fila con color `danger` y que ponga "i'm vertically centered" y debajo otra fila con color `warning` y que ponga tambien "i'm vertically centered". Y que por supuesto ambas filas esten centradas verticalmente.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex h-100">
            <div class="row align-items-center bg-danger w-100">
                <div class="col-6 mx-auto bg-info">
                    I'm vertically centered    
                </div>   
            </div> 
            <div class="row align-items-center bg-warning w-100">
                <div class="col-6 mx-auto bg-info">
                    I'm vertically centered    
                </div>            
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Si en lugar de `d-flex` pongo `d-block` en el contanier me aparece en dos filas distintas pero no aparece alineado al centro verticalmente.
Por cierto en el navegador (tanto en firefox como en chrome) las dos filas (la danger y la warning) ocupan todo el alto de la pantalla cosa que no sucede en el snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center bg-danger h-50">
            <div class="col-12 mx-auto bg-info">
                I'm vertically centered    
            </div>   
        </div> 
        <div class="row align-items-center bg-warning h-50">
            <div class="col-12 mx-auto bg-info">
                I'm vertically centered    
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

El container no debe ser display: flex, y los row siempre son display: flex por defecto, por lo que funciona agregando solo a los rows un align-items center, luego a cada row le puse un h-50 que es equivalente a height: 50%;
De esta forma quedan 2 Rows una encima de la otra, con sus cols adentro alineadas verticalmente.

Espero te sirva.

Por último vi que tienes cols de 6, entonces estás usando el mx-auto para centrarlas, eso funciona, quizás podrías usar también ya que estás utilizando flexbox aplicar justify-content-center.. Quedaría así:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center bg-danger h-50">
            <div class="col-6 bg-info">
                I'm vertically centered    
            </div>   
        </div> 
        <div class="row align-items-center bg-warning h-50">
            <div class="col-6 mx-auto bg-info">
                I'm vertically centered    
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

La primer row está hecha con justify-content-center y la segunda con mx-auto. En estos casos ya estaría centrada horizontal y verticalmente..

Comment: genial! muchas gracias.

Comment: Por nada, a las órdenes!